# NSDateFormat dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Was wondering if there is an easy conversion to take a date in the format dd/MM/yyyy and transform it to MM/dd/yyyy to display.

Current code tried is:

```
   //in dd/MM/yyyy format string below.
   NSString *stringToFormat = @"28/05/1991";

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

   NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToFormat];
```

However, date will return nil in this situation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please search. There are countless examples of how to convert a date string from one format to another.

Comment: @rmaddy : I will upvote if you put above comment as answer with google search link :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar That wouldn't be an answer, just a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to "**decode**" and then "**encode**". You're currently trying to parse `28` as a month. Try this:

```
//in dd/MM/yyyy format string below.
NSString *stringToFormat = @"28/05/1991";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToFormat];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```